# an INSERT...SELECT with empty VALUES too

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want insert data from another incomplete table, so some values must be empty in NOT NULL fields.

For example, I have two tables : people and peopleTemp.

In ***people*** table, I have a lot of fields : *permit_number*, *first_name*, *last_name*, *gender*, *tel*, etc. In ***peopleTemp*** table, I have only *permit_number*, *first_name*, *last_name* and a special field *updated*, set after an UPDATE query.

Now I want insert person they are'nt present in ***people***. *Gender* and *tel* are NOT NULL, but must be empty. I try :

```
INSERT INTO people p1 (gender, tel, permit_number, first_name, last_name)
                VALUES ('','', (
                SELECT permit_number, first_name, last_name
                FROM peopleTemp p2
                WHERE p2.updated = 0))
```

But I get this error : `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Can you help me to resolve this situation ? Thank you in advance !

Additional question : Can I `SET p2.updated = 1` at the end of the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your syntax error by using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO people p1 (gender, tel, permit_number, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT '', '', permit_number, first_name, last_name
    FROM peopleTemp p2
    WHERE p2.updated = 0;
```

I would suggest that you use `NULL` instead of an empty string to represent a missing value.

Comment: Thank you! I agree for `NULL` but the database is unfortunately made like this.

Answer (score 0):

For your additional question .. No, you can't. `SET` works with `UPDATE..` . If you want to update the `p2.updated = 1` after you done your `INSERT`, you have to run an additional `UPDATE` query on the `peopleTemp` table `JOIN` with `people` table for validation. Something like below should work:

```
... after you done INSERT query suggested by Gordon

UPDATE peopleTemp p2 
JOIN   people p1
ON     p2.permit_number=p1.permit_number 
AND    p2.first_name=p1.first_name
AND    p2.last_name=p1.last_name
SET    p2.updated=1
WHERE  P2.updated=0;
```